# Why was this Spam or Offensive? Can this be reversed?

Tags: support

I just noticed that this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257932/205310) was deleted as spam or offensive. I understand the deletion because it's not an "answer", but this was NOT SPAM or OFFENSIVE!

**Can someone please reverse this, as it affects my reputation and credibility**

I may only be a newbie and still finding my feet but I can't see why this was considered spam or offensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited the post to make it look less like a subtle advert for wondershare and moved it to comments. That's not a normal thing, but you have a reasonable comment and it might help the site get a better answer to the question you linked.

Going forward, try to find some other questions to answer. Once you've gotten a few positive posts (answers specifically) voted - any temporary down side to deleted posts will be a distant memory.

Comment: Deletions due to spam or offensive flags cause a -100 reputation penalty — not exactly a temporary down side!

Comment: @grgarside new users never go below a point, so this case, the [flag cost 13 reputation points](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/205310/little-eden?tab=reputation). Less than one accepted answer. Even 100 isn't overly harsh for someone that knows how they got to 100 in the first place.

Comment: Of course, but that's only true in this specific case where the user did not have much reputation, and the less reputation you have the more the small reputation matters because that affects access to privileges.

Comment: @grgarside In the rare event that this would be necessary, a moderator can delete all _rude or abusive_ and _spam_ flags on a post, which also removes any automatic Community downvotes.